# ElasticSearch Restricting Index, Field creation for Production

Tags: elasticsearch

For production I would like to restrict ElasticSearch automatic index creation. As per the documentation I have restricted the server *elasticsearch.yml*

```
action.auto_create_index
index.mapper.dynamic: false
```

However I'm stable to insert new documents with fields that do not match the custom mapping?

Answer (score 2):

According to [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-dynamic-mapping.html), I think `dynamic mapping` should be set to `strict`.

> The dynamic creation of fields within a type can be completely disabled by setting the dynamic property of the type to strict.